# What's meen AVC block list?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 and in Developer options i have

> turn off AVC block list

What's this option mean?

Comment: Do you mean AVC black list?

Comment: Yes spelling error. It's AVC but no black list.

Comment: As searching the web indicates, it's likely related to call blocking. There is a thread in the Samsung forums as well.

Comment: I suspect the web will return you roughly the same results I got when I searched first for "Samsung AVS block list" then the correct "Samsung AVC black list".

Comment: Yes It is. but i'm sure that this it the correct answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A moderator on the samsung community website defines it as below.
(pasted)

> SamsungLou
> Samsung Moderator
> ‎07-05-2021 03:18 PM in Tablets
>
> AVC stands for Advanced Video Coding. It is used by app
> developers to keep non-compliant codecs from interfering with their
> apps...

(it is **AVC block list** in Android 10 dev options)

https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Tablets/AVC-block-list/td-p/1839537

Just so you know... Both times I visited this site it gave me an SSOError. I either reloaded or was forced to click directly without a opening new tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see, that should be a quote (from the link provided) along with who said it.